# Struts2 (modeldriven) update method setting fields which do not exist on form to null

Tags: struts2

I am forced to put all non view fields as HIDDEN on JSP page, to have it values transferred.

Is there a way to retain the values of non form fields without using `HIDDEN`.

Comment: Why to have hidden fields to be set to null?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that, Fields in your Model are `member variables` & if `member variables` are not initialized then they are by default set to their default values i.e string to null, int to 0.

If values you are passing as a hidden are not going to change then set those values to the fields of model inside your action class instead of passing that from jsp.